# Applying css to a table in popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some nested DIVs & a table at the bottom of a page that I want to display in a new window when the user double clicks on a specific div within the page.  When the host page is loaded, the contents of the div are not visible.  Using IE11 & jQuery.  Some of the code:

```
<div id="dbg" display="none">
    <div id="dbginner">
        <table id="tblDbg">
           <tr>
             <td>DebugInfo</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td><div id="dbgVal1"></div></td>
           </tr>
    </div>
</div>
```

In document.ready, I have:

```
$("#dbgDiv").dblclick(function() {
    var dbwin = window.open("","mypage","width=1200, height=600,scrollbars=yes");
    var $dbwin = $(dbwin.document.body);
    $dbwin.append( $("#dbg").html() );
    $dbwin.css({"background":"yellow"});
});
```

When the #dbgDiv is double-clicked, the page opens & is populated with the table (2 rows), and the background of the new page is yellow.  There is the header (first row), and the debug value that I populate.

What I want to do is to apply css values to the table which is in the newly opened page to put borders on the table rows & columns, and format other things within that new window (and eventually close it).

What I don't want to happen is for the css to be applied to both the DIV in the new page and also the div which is in my main page (which gets populated with my debug info).  The DIV in my main page is to always be hidden; the only time that info should be visible is when the new window opens.  It should be visible there only, never visible inside the main page.

How can you apply the style changes to the new window only?

Comment: if you plan to use inline css don't forget the style attribute (`<div id="dbg" style="display: none">` instead of `<div id="dbg" display="none">`

Comment: And you could add an extra class to you popups' `#dbg`, then in your css use that as selector for you styles.

Comment: I'm able to add a class to the div and/or the table in the popup window, but the css I have for the calling page isn't being applied.  Does it need to be done a different way?

Comment: Is it being loaded? (check your inspector / developer tools)

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

```
display="none"
```

should be changed to

```
style="display: none"
```

and to modify the newly opened page, the code must be run on the newly created page and not after window.open()